# Further simplify this $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{k}{{k \choose i} \cdot 12^i \cdot 2^i}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

Could we further simplify this:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{k}{{k \choose i} \cdot  12^i \cdot 2^i}$$

or, at least, find a close upper bound?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, note that $12^i * 2^i$ is nothing more than $24^i$.

So consider $1 + \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k}{{k \choose i} \times  12^i \times 2^i} = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{k}{{k \choose i} \times  24^i} = (1 + 24)^k$. (by the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)).

So your sum is nothing more than $25^k - 1$.

Comment: Great, thanks also for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: lookup [Binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Comment: keeping in mind that $12^i\times 2^i$ is just $(12\times 2)^i$ ;)

Comment: I don't know if that was homework or not, anyway it was quite simple and I think we should have let the OP figure the details out. Too late now…

Answer (score 1):

$(1+24)^k=\sum\limits_{i = 0}^k {{k \choose i}24^i }$.